# std::Map return empty after a loop C++

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have a issue similar to [C++ map empty after inserting data.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54023030/c-map-empty-after-inserting-data), where text files are read and a map is updated for each key that the file holds. But I don't loop inside a Class, but inside N .txt files given by the user, so the solution isn't clear for me. I also declared the map outside the loop, as suggested here [Why does map become empty outside the (switch) case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63413098/why-does-map-become-empty-outside-the-switch-case).

Here goes a piece of my code:

```
    string language = {};
    vector<vector<string>> language_content;

    //IDkey,                           <LanguageKey      ,      Thanslation>        
    /*               */ /*                  de                  abbruch             */
    /*   btnexit     */ /*                  en                  cancel              */
    /*               */ /*                  es                  cancelar            */

    /*               */ /*                  de                  bestätigen          */
    /*   btnconfirm  */ /* ´                en                  confirm             */
    /*               */ /*                  es                  confirmacìon        */

    // Create a map of strings to strings
    //de | bestätigung
    map<string, string> Languagekey_Translation;

    // Create a map of strings to maps
    map<string, map<string, string>> IDkey_LanguageTranslation;

    for (int i = 0; i < txt_filepath.size(); i++)
    {
        language = readTXT(txt_filepath[i], language_content);
        fillCorpus(language, language_content, Languagekey_Translation, IDkey_LanguageTranslation);
    }
```

And here is `fillCorpus()` code:

```
void fillCorpus (string language, vector<vector<string>> language_content, map<string, string> Languagekey_Translation, map<string, map<string, string>> IDkey_LanguageTranslation)
    {   
        map<string, map<string, string>>::iterator itr1;
        map<string, string>::iterator itr2;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < language_content.size(); i++) {
    
            string keyID = language_content[i][0];
            string translation = language_content[i][1];
            Languagekey_Translation.clear();
            Languagekey_Translation.insert(make_pair(language, translation));
    
            //is this keyID already used?
            itr1 = IDkey_LanguageTranslation.find(keyID);
    
            if (itr1 != IDkey_LanguageTranslation.end()) {
                //if already used (found) 
                itr1->second.insert(make_pair(language, translation));
            }
            else {
                //if not already used (not found), save it
                IDkey_LanguageTranslation[keyID] = Languagekey_Translation;
            }
        }
    }
```

I would appreciate any help from the community.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be passing objects *by value* to the functions that are supposed to modify the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [@Some programmer dude] ([std::Map return empty after a loop C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75695893/stdmap-return-empty-after-a-loop-c?noredirect=1#comment133539266_75695893))! my programm is now able to take by reference the Map and therefore consistently looping and adding new information. Thank you!

```
void fillCorpus (string language, vector<vector<string>> language_content, map<string, string> &Languagekey_Translation, map<string, map<string, string>> &IDkey_LanguageTranslation)
```

Comment: I recommend you pass the `language` and `language_content` arguments by (`const`) references as well, to avoid unnecessary copying.